# Is it correсt to name such versioning a semver?

Tags: continuous-integration, version, artifacts, semantic-versioning

Good day, fellows.

System architect and some developers from my company have said, that to use:

1. For minor version - the number of merge requests
2. For patch - the number of commits

is the semantic versioning.

I have read the `semver spec` and I can't find anything similar. Am I correct or not?

PS: it's not a joke, it's real and we use it in our CI pipeline, proof (our artifact in Harbor docker registry): https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7dqp.png

Comment: If you came up with a different "solution" please, let us know, otherwise, accept my answer. Both could be useful for other users looking for the same answer 

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it can't! The number of commits doesn't represent the number of bug fixes (a bug fix could also require 100 commits) and the number of merge requests doesn't represent the number of added features (10 merge requests could be 10 bug fixes but no one new feature).

But in your company, that's an internal standard and probably it's really helpful internally. So, keep up with it even if you can't call it's a "real" semver